# Why would this result in a segmentation fault?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, segmentation-fault

Why do I get segmentation fault here? n=100, rows =100 columns =3

```
int* dynamicArray(int n, int queries_rows, int queries_columns, int** queries, int* result_count) {
    int *result=(int*)malloc(queries_rows*sizeof(int*));
    int **arr=(int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int *));
    
    int count_seq[n];
    int lastAnswer=0;
    int size;
    int e=0;   
    int seq;
    int count=0;
    int x,y;
    int c;
    int a=0;
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        count_seq[j]=0;
    }
     for(int j=0;j<queries_rows;j++){
        result[j]=0;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<queries_rows;i++){
        if(queries[i][0]==1){
            x=queries[i][1];
            
            seq=(x^lastAnswer)%n;
           
            count_seq[seq]=(count_seq[seq])+1;
            arr[seq] = realloc(arr[seq],(count_seq[seq]+1)*sizeof(int));
            c=count_seq[seq];
            a=c-1;
            y=queries[i][2];
            arr[seq][a]=y;
          
        }else{
            
            x=queries[i][1];
            seq=(x^lastAnswer)%n;

            y=queries[i][2];
            c=count_seq[seq];
            size=c;
            if(size==0) break;
            y=y%size;
            count=count+1;
            lastAnswer=arr[seq][y];
            result[e]=lastAnswer;
            printf("%d\n",lastAnswer);
            e++;
        }
     
    }
    *result_count = count;
    free(arr);
    return result;
}
```

I receive a segmentation fault with this code only when the value of n and queries_rows is input as 100. Queries columns is always equals to 3 and queries is a 2d array. The first column always has value 1 or 2

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Remember, the **tags** attract the right audience to your question, so if you use irrelevant tags you get the wrong audience and the audience you want don't see that question.

Comment: e.g. [edit] the question and add tags for the programming language you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
int *result=(int*)malloc(queries_rows*sizeof(int*));
```

You are assigning memory of the size of 'n' integer pointers for an integer pointer.

It should be:

```
int *result=(int*)malloc(queries_rows*sizeof(int));
```

And, this is not the way to dynamically allocate memory in C:

```
int count_seq[n];
```

Comment: I get the same segmentation fault even after correcting this. I should also add that I get a segmentation fault only for the above mentioned inputs, it works fine for even larger values of n. This is a problem for the data structure section in hacker rank